# How to update the git tag automatically when I do a commit --amend

Tags: git

If I do `git commit --amend` to a tagged commit, the tag will disappeared. I need to delete the original tag and add it again. Is there any way to move the original tag to the new commit?

Comment: When you do a `git commit --amend`, you are creating an entirely new commit, so your question is the same as asking how to move a tag from one commit to another one.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot directly tie [the creation of a new commit (`--amend`)](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-commit--amend) and a tag (which [still references the original commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3143658/6309)).

You would need to move the tag (keeping its old message) and delete/replace the tag on remote.
[Juan Antonio Tubío](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4599564/juan-antonio-tub%C3%ADo) has an [interesting set of alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30383309/6309) to facilitate that sequence:

```
# Return date of tag. (To use in another alias)
tag-date = "!git show $1 | awk '{ if ($1 == \"Date:\") { print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }}' | tail -2 | head -1 #"

# Show tag message
tag-message = "!git show $1 | awk -v capture=0 '{ if(capture) message=message\"\\n\"$0}; BEGIN {message=\"\"}; { if ($1 == \"Date:\" && length(message)==0 ) {capture=1}; if ($1 == \"commit\" ) {capture=0}  }; END { print message }' | sed '$ d' | cat -s #"

### Move tag. Use: git tagm <tagname> <newcommit> 
tagm = "!GIT_TAG_MESSAGE=$(git tag-message $1) && GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git tag-date $1) && git tag-message $1 && git tag -d $1 && git tag -a $1 $2 -m \"$GIT_TAG_MESSAGE\" #"

### Move pushed tag. Use: git tagmp <tagname> <newcommit> 
tagmp = "!git tagm $1 $2 && git push --delete origin $1 && git push origin $1 #"
```

Once you have amended your commit (with a new SHA1 ), you would type:

```
git tagm <yourTag> <sha>
```