# git commit amendment without losing the tags

Tags: git, git-tag, git-amend

I have the following script that runs on post-commit hook of Git:

```
#!/bin/sh
# by Martin Seeler, and
# by Jorge Javier Araya Navarro

# destination of the final changelog file
OUTPUT_FILE=CHANGELOG.md

# generate the changelog
if ! type gitchangelog > /dev/null; then
    echo "ERROR: Please install gitchangelog"
    exit 1
fi

gitchangelog > $OUTPUT_FILE

# prevent recursion!
# since a 'commit --amend' will trigger the post-commit script again
# we have to check if the changelog file has changed or not
res=$(git status --porcelain | grep $OUTPUT_FILE | wc -l)
if [ "$res" -gt 0 ]; then
  git add $OUTPUT_FILE
  git commit --amend --no-edit
  echo "Populated Changelog in $OUTPUT_FILE"
fi
```

This is convenient for generating a CHANGELOG file using gitchangelog without creating a new commit to register the change on that file.

However, if I had a tag on HEAD, after `commit --amend` is ran the tag is *"lost"*, thus I have to delete it locally and remotely and recreate it which is annoying.

I'm trying to figure a way for the script to move the tags after the amend, but at this point I not sure what I'm doing. Should I list first the tags on HEAD? May I move the tags after the amend? Will Git know what I mean anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [`git tagm` alias I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34892535/6309) in order to move your tag after a `git commit --amend`.

That would automate the sequence of:

- finding the tag,
- moving (ie recreating it)
- deleting the old one.

Comment: Any idea on how to get a list of tags on HEAD for later use with the alias?

Comment: @shackra you could list those tags just before the amend with https://stackoverflow.com/a/15353441/6309:  `git tag --points-at HEAD`